# How can you get a JTextField to work in a SQLite Select statement?

Tags: java, database, sqlite, swing, jtextfield

I am working on a program which will when finished allow the end user to  keep track of there sound packs in a database through SQLite. The newest problem I am running into is that I can not get the Select statement to take a `JTextField` input. The reason that I want to do this is that I already have the text fields linked through the insert method. I have tried switching the variable types in the `readAllData` method and I am not entirely sure what other way to fix it.

The fields are as follows

- PackId
- PackName
- VendorName
- PackValue

what I want to happen is when I hit the Update button I want the data in the database to print out to the console (for now) and I am also going to be adding a select specified records method as well.

Here is the code I do apologize in advance this is a very long project:

```
public void readAllData() throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:packsver3.db");
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM packs";
       ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
       rs = ps.executeQuery();
       while(rs.next()) {
         String  PackId = PackId.getText();
           String  PackName = PackName.getText();
           String  VendorName = VendorName.getTextField();
           String PackValue = rs.getTextField;
    
    System.out.println("All Packs\n");
    System.out.println("PackId: " +PackId);
    System.out.println("PackName: " +PackName);
    System.out.println("VendorName: " +VendorName);
    System.out.println("PackValue: " +PackValue+"\n\n");
       }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }finally {
        try {
            assert rs != null;
            rs.close();
            ps.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
```

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eu18F.png)

Comment: Oracle has a complete tutorial, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html), which will help you learn the correct way to create a Swing GUI.  Skip the Netbeans section.  Swing is designed to work with [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).  Take a look at the code in this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66841789/how-do-i-add-an-actionlistener-to-a-jcheckbox/66844172#66844172) for an example of how to organize you Swing code.

Comment: I have tried using layout managers but for my purposes they make it much more difficult and some of my components would not go where I wanted regardless of the layout used.

Comment: *my components would not go where I wanted regardless of the layout used* - then you are using the layout managers incorrectly. You can always nest panels using different layout managers to achieve your desired layout. *I want the data in the database to print out to the console* - so why do you have hundreds of lines of code? Create a simple class that 1) builds your SQL statement 2) executes the query and 3) displays the results on the console. All the other code you posted is irrelevant to the question and is too much code. Post a proper [mre].

Comment: The part I am working on is  the update section which is a part of the program

Comment: The rest of your program is irrelevant to the question. You learn to problem solve by simplifying the problem. I've suggested how you can simplify the problem if you want help.

Comment: I simplified what I posted to just the readAllData method which should make it easier to read.

Comment: Why are you trying to use the getText() method of a text field? If you are trying to get data from the database why do you not get data from the ResultSet? Read the ResultSet API for the appropriate "getter" method to use. You can also search this site or the web for examples that use a ResultSet.